# std::string _M_leak_hard and performance concerns

Tags: c++, string

While profiling a C++ application, I've noticed that the following code:

```
std::string s;
int i;

dict[s[i]] ++;
```

yields an invokation of (inline) `std::string::_M_leak_hard`, chaining into `std::string::_M_mutate` and more (gcc-4.7.3), and going through an insane number of CPU instructions comparing internal state of string, at what should've been a const context and optimized away to a simple memory read.

Am I doing something terribly wrong? That chain of std::string implementation-specific detail burns easily through 50% of the CPU time.

Comment: What compiler? What optimization flags? What type is `dict`?

Comment: Did you initialize the `i` and `s` before using them? It's unclear from your code, and if you didn't, you probably try to access a memory that doesn't belong to the string.

Comment: Try using the "real" string in `ext/vstring.h` (e.g. `typedef __gnu_ext::__vstring string`).

Comment: yes, it's all initialized, the code performs flawlessly under valgrind's memory access debugger, but reviewing it under 'callgrind' demonstrates that the compiler used the 'non-const' operator[], even at LHS. `dict` is an int['z'-'a'] array, and, besides, access outside of string bounds should *not* be checked when using operator[] - that's what the method .at() is for.

Comment: ok, creating an inline function for this piece of code, and hinting the compiler by passing the strings by reference to this inline function with const-qualifier worked. That is, `__do_work(const std::string &s) - this happily compiled into 4 assembly instructions, as expected.

Comment: I'm guessing this is because GCC's (now non-standard) implementation of `std::string` performs copy-on-write semantics. I've heard this will change in GCC4.9

Comment: Yeah, it seems so - I'm curious why gcc chose the mutable path for this LHS use, thou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you are looking at is indeed the *unsharing* in the gcc implementation of `std::string`. As of why the compiler *chose the mutable path for this LHS*, the answer is simple: that is how overload resolution. The operator to use is picked by checking the arguments and the object on which the operator is called. In this case, the object is non-const and thus the non-const overload is picked up.

You could try to force picking up the const overload with a minimal change in the code:

```
std::string s = ..;
int i = ..;

const std::string& r = s;
++dict[r[i]];
```

Where the main change is creating a const reference to the object to force the use of the const overload of `operator[]`

Comment: Yup, that's the same concept. It's important to keep these implementation details in mind when dealing with std::string - this change resulted in ~60% speedup (apparently it also helped with cache locality and other issues).

Comment: @qdot: Note that in C++11 (proper) copy-on-write is forbidden.